# Firebase deploy to another site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase Hosting to deploy my app

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 apps: `clone-a50db` and `clone-eeb88` and the app `clone-eeb88` is already in use, so now I want to deploy my app to the other which is `clone-a50db`.

This is how I did:

```
firebase init
? Are you ready to proceed? Yes
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites` 

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, using clone-eeb88.

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.`

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
+  Wrote build/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!`
```

```
npm run build
```

```
firebase deploy --only hosting` (because I already deployed function in advanced)
```

It worked but instead of deploy to `clone-a50db`, it deployed to `clone-eeb88`, it is feasible because it is using default project which is `clone-eeb88` as it told in the setup, please tell me how to switch my site, thank you so much and happy new year

*firebase.json*

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to specify target for hosting where you wish to deploy. here is a wonderful documentation to solve your problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets. Refer to `firebase.json` file to configure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

** UPDATED **
What you actually want is "Multihosting".
To manage two different versions of the same sites, you have to separate them by the **targets** in your `firebase.json -> hosting` file, something like this:

[Here is the example template project on GitHub where I'm using a Firebase Multihosting support](https://github.com/danieltorscho/gcp-quasar/tree/multisite-support).

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "alpha",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "beta",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Instead of using "site" property inside your `firebase.json` like before, now you have to set it manually first like so:

```
firebase target:apply hosting alpha clone-eeb88
firebase target:apply hosting beta clone-a50db
```

Afterwards, you will be able to use your Firebase CLI commands like so:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:alpha
firebase deploy --only hosting:beta
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it sounds promising but I got this error, how can i fix this

Comment: $ firebase deploy --only hosting:clone-a50db
!  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.

=== Deploying to 'clone-eeb88'...

i  deploying hosting

Error: Hosting configs should only include either "site" or "target", not both.

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help

Comment: answer updated, I believe they've made some changes to their firebase configuration. Now instead of defining site and target in one place, you should do define target in json file and only after apply that target to your firebase resource (name of your site) via CLI